# System.Exception - Maybe something to do with my timer

Tags: c#, windows

So I have come to a problem that I have never had before and I cant find any information about my specific problem. Basically when i start the program i have a panel that displays time and weather information. When i start it, the weather is refreshed as well as the time with no problem (The problem starts at //ERROR HERE!!!) I think this probably has something to do with the timer because it works all fine without the timer but I need it so i can constantly refresh the time & weather. I will include the error at the end.

What could be the cause of this? If you need any more information let me know!

```
public async void WeatherInfoRefresh()
{
    TimeRefresh();

    RootObject myWeather = await CurrentWeather.GetWeather("Adelaide");

    ResultTextBlock.Text = myWeather.name + " • " + myWeather.main.temp + "°C";

    if (myWeather.weather[0].description == "broken clouds")
    {
    WeatherImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Files/AAA/brokenclouds.png"));
    }
}
```

My timer voids:

```
public void startTimer()
{
    ticker = new Timer(TimerMethod, null, 30000, 3000);
}

public void TimerMethod(object state)
{
    WeatherInfoRefresh();
}
```

My time refresh void:

```
public void TimeRefresh()
{
    //Timedate
    DayTextBlock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd"); //ERROR HERE - This almost always works without the timer!!!
    DateTextBlock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM");
    TimeTextBlock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt");
}
```

And the error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Mashy Home Automation.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
```

Comment: Never invoke GUI behaviour from an `async` function, or in general one from another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timer and UI run on different threads, you cannot update the UI from the timer thread.

Comment: To add on to the answer, there are timers that do fire their elapsed event on the UI thread. Use a [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are using WPF, or a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are using Winforms.

Comment: Yeah I knew It had something to do with that, This is just an explanation to the problem, Can you give me a way to solve this?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain So i should use a dispatch timer?

Comment: @GurfX if you are using WPF, yes.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do right now but ran into a problem. Something is wrong with this code and the error is: "No overload for "timer_Tick" matches delegate "EventHandler <object>"" What can i do?

`public MainPage()

    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }
    
    void timer_Tick(EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeRefresh();
    }`

Comment: timer_Tick has the wrong method signature i guess. should be void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)